# Qry runs too long and index didn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing

I created an index to help a really long 28 minute qry run faster and it doesn't seem to have helped to much.

This is the Index I created

```
USE [NLTR201212_test]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Billys Index, sysname,]
ON [dbo].[tblInsurance] ([TERM_REASON])
INCLUDE ([POLICY_NO],[IssueYear],[ISSUE_DATE],[LM_PLAN_CODE],[AMOUNT_INFORCE],[StatReserve],[StatReserveX],[DefPremReserve],[ExcessCashValue],[ExcessCashValueX],[STAT2_PUA_RES],[STAT2_OYT_RES],[StatOYTRes2X],[COMPANY_CODE],[PHASE_CODE],[SUB_PHASE_CODE],[ProdType])
GO
```

This is the first index I've ever created so I wouldn't be surprised if I did it wrong somehow. `TblInsurance` does have a primary key made up from five columns (`COMPANY_CODE, LINE_OFBUSINESS, POLICY_NO, PHASE_CODE` and `SUB_PHASE_CODE`) already.

Not sure what else to do to help the situation.

This is the qry,

```
SELECT 
    qry_tempCashValue2.IssueYear, 
    qry_tempCashValue2.LM_PLAN_CODE, 
    Count(qry_tempCashValue2.POLICY_NO) AS CountOfPOLICY_NO, 
    qry_tempCashValue2.[Interest Rate Code]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        qry_tempCashValue.POLICY_NO, 
        qry_tempCashValue.IssueYear, 
        qry_tempCashValue.ISSUE_DATE, 
        qry_tempCashValue.LM_PLAN_CODE, 
        qry_tempCashValue.AMOUNT_INFORCE, 
        qry_tempCashValue.StatReserve, 
        qry_tempCashValue.StatReserveX, 
        qry_tempCashValue.DefPremReserve, 
        qry_tempCashValue.ExcessCashValue, 
        qry_tempCashValue.ExcessCashValueX, 
        qry_tempCashValue.STAT2_PUA_RES, 
        qry_tempCashValue.STAT2_OYT_RES, 
        qry_tempCashValue.StatOYTRes2X, 
        qry_tempCashValue.[Calc Parameters Code], 
        Max(qry_tempCashValue.[Low Issue Date]) AS [MaxOfLow Issue Date], 
        qry_tempCashValue.[Interest Rate Code]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            tblInsurance.POLICY_NO, 
            tblInsurance.IssueYear, 
            tblInsurance.ISSUE_DATE, 
            tblInsurance.LM_PLAN_CODE, 
            tblInsurance.AMOUNT_INFORCE, 
            tblInsurance.StatReserve, 
            tblInsurance.StatReserveX, 
            tblInsurance.DefPremReserve, 
            tblInsurance.ExcessCashValue, 
            tblInsurance.ExcessCashValueX, 
            tblInsurance.STAT2_PUA_RES, 
            tblInsurance.STAT2_OYT_RES, 
            tblInsurance.StatOYTRes2X, 
            qryPolyCalcParameters.[Calc Parameters Code], 
            qryPolyCalcParameters.[Low Issue Date], 
            qryPolyCalcParameters.[Interest Rate Code]
        FROM tblInsurance 
        INNER JOIN qryPolyLifeMasterPlans 
            ON tblInsurance.LM_PLAN_CODE = 
                qryPolyLifeMasterPlans.[LifeMaster Plan Code] 
        INNER JOIN qryPolyNonforfeitureValues 
            ON qryPolyLifeMasterPlans.[Nonforfeiture Value Code] = 
                qryPolyNonforfeitureValues.[Nonforfeiture Value Code] 
        INNER JOIN qryPolyCalcParameters 
            ON qryPolyNonforfeitureValues.[(Cash Value) Calc Parameters Code] = 
                qryPolyCalcParameters.[Calc Parameters Code]
        WHERE 
            qryPolyCalcParameters.[Low Issue Date]<[ISSUE_DATE] 
            AND tblInsurance.COMPANY_CODE='NL' 
            AND tblInsurance.LINE_OF_BUSINESS='IT' 
            AND tblInsurance.SchedNP='PAR'
            AND tblInsurance.TERM_REASON='A' 
            AND tblInsurance.ProdType='PERM' 
            AND tblInsurance.PHASE_CODE=0 
            AND tblInsurance.SUB_PHASE_CODE=1 
        ) qry_tempCashValue
    GROUP BY 
        qry_tempCashValue.POLICY_NO, 
        qry_tempCashValue.IssueYear, 
        qry_tempCashValue.ISSUE_DATE, 
        qry_tempCashValue.LM_PLAN_CODE, 
        qry_tempCashValue.AMOUNT_INFORCE, 
        qry_tempCashValue.StatReserve, 
        qry_tempCashValue.StatReserveX, 
        qry_tempCashValue.DefPremReserve, 
        qry_tempCashValue.ExcessCashValue, 
        qry_tempCashValue.ExcessCashValueX, 
        qry_tempCashValue.STAT2_PUA_RES, 
        qry_tempCashValue.STAT2_OYT_RES, 
        qry_tempCashValue.StatOYTRes2X, 
        qry_tempCashValue.[Calc Parameters Code], 
        qry_tempCashValue.[Interest Rate Code]
    ) qry_tempCashValue2
GROUP BY 
    qry_tempCashValue2.IssueYear, 
    qry_tempCashValue2.LM_PLAN_CODE, 
    qry_tempCashValue2.[Interest Rate Code];

GO
```

Comment: A table can only ever have **one** primary key, by definition. You're probably talking about a primary key **made up of 5 columns** - right? And which ones would those be??

Comment: Yes Thats what I mean. The columns are COMPANY_CODE LINE_OFBUSINESS POLICY_NO PHASE_CODE and SUB_PHASE_CODE. The the table tblinsurance is around 300,000 rows

Comment: All of those columns most definitely **do not** belong into your nonclustered index - they're already part of it anyway.

Comment: would that prevent the index from working properly?

Comment: The query optimizer uses a lot of factors to decide what approach to take - no quick'n'easy answers here.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can turn the query into this:

```
SELECT 
    qry_tempCashValue.IssueYear, 
    qry_tempCashValue.LM_PLAN_CODE, 
    Count(distinct qry_tempCashValue.POLICY_NO) AS CountOfPOLICY_NO, 
    qry_tempCashValue.[Interest Rate Code]
FROM
(
        SELECT 
            tblInsurance.POLICY_NO, 
            tblInsurance.IssueYear, 
            tblInsurance.ISSUE_DATE, 
            tblInsurance.LM_PLAN_CODE, 
            tblInsurance.AMOUNT_INFORCE, 
            tblInsurance.StatReserve, 
            tblInsurance.StatReserveX, 
            tblInsurance.DefPremReserve, 
            tblInsurance.ExcessCashValue, 
            tblInsurance.ExcessCashValueX, 
            tblInsurance.STAT2_PUA_RES, 
            tblInsurance.STAT2_OYT_RES, 
            tblInsurance.StatOYTRes2X, 
            qryPolyCalcParameters.[Calc Parameters Code], 
            qryPolyCalcParameters.[Low Issue Date], 
            qryPolyCalcParameters.[Interest Rate Code]
        FROM tblInsurance 
        INNER JOIN qryPolyLifeMasterPlans 
            ON tblInsurance.LM_PLAN_CODE = 
                qryPolyLifeMasterPlans.[LifeMaster Plan Code] 
        INNER JOIN qryPolyNonforfeitureValues 
            ON qryPolyLifeMasterPlans.[Nonforfeiture Value Code] = 
                qryPolyNonforfeitureValues.[Nonforfeiture Value Code] 
        INNER JOIN qryPolyCalcParameters 
            ON qryPolyNonforfeitureValues.[(Cash Value) Calc Parameters Code] = 
                qryPolyCalcParameters.[Calc Parameters Code]
        WHERE 
            qryPolyCalcParameters.[Low Issue Date]<[ISSUE_DATE] 
            AND tblInsurance.COMPANY_CODE='NL' 
            AND tblInsurance.LINE_OF_BUSINESS='IT' 
            AND tblInsurance.SchedNP='PAR'
            AND tblInsurance.TERM_REASON='A' 
            AND tblInsurance.ProdType='PERM' 
            AND tblInsurance.PHASE_CODE=0 
            AND tblInsurance.SUB_PHASE_CODE=1 
        ) qry_tempCashValue
GROUP BY 
    qry_tempCashValue.IssueYear, 
    qry_tempCashValue.LM_PLAN_CODE, 
    qry_tempCashValue.[Interest Rate Code];
```

This eliminates the inner aggregation and counts the policies using `count(distinct)`.  Depending on your data, this may not return the same results.

As for indexes, a good place to start is to have an index on the key for each table used in the join.  And another on all the columns in the `where` clause on `tblInsrance` that use `=`.

Comment: I get an error highlighting the first select and the last group by

Comment: I elminated the 2 from tempcashvalues and it seems to have fixed that problem and I am now testing the qry. Unsure if I will get the same results however

Comment: I've heard that something called a Temp Table may also be helpful what do you think of this?

Comment: @Gordan Linoff This actually helped shave 3 minutes off and it grabbed all the same information. Unfortunetly its still much too long.

Comment: @user2379197 . . . This type of query does not need temporary tables.  You are doing a fairly common type of query, joining together some tables and aggregating the results.

Comment: @Gordan Linoff Well do you have any other suggestions to increase performance. I thought about your comment on indexes but tblInsurance is the only tbl use in this qry therefore the only factor that indexes can effect.

Comment: @user2379197 . . . I would start with the index on the `where` clause fields in `tblInsurance`.  After that, it probably gets hard.  I'm guessing that the references starting with "qry" are really views.  You can consider indexed views or finding the right indexes for optimizing them.

Comment: @Gordan Linoff Yes they are views. The fields in teh where clause are either in the current index or part of the primary key index. I'm beginning to think that there is no way to improve performance any further short of creating tables based on the views and using them instead of running the qry's.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than focusing on adding indices, I think you should clean up your query.  I don't know why you are nesting this, instead of just doing the group by and the select all at once.

```
    SELECT 
        tblInsurance.POLICY_NO, 
        tblInsurance.IssueYear, 
        tblInsurance.ISSUE_DATE, 
        tblInsurance.LM_PLAN_CODE, 
        tblInsurance.AMOUNT_INFORCE, 
        tblInsurance.StatReserve, 
        tblInsurance.StatReserveX, 
        tblInsurance.DefPremReserve, 
        tblInsurance.ExcessCashValue, 
        tblInsurance.ExcessCashValueX, 
        tblInsurance.STAT2_PUA_RES, 
        tblInsurance.STAT2_OYT_RES, 
        tblInsurance.StatOYTRes2X, 
        qryPolyCalcParameters.[Calc Parameters Code], 
        max(qryPolyCalcParameters.[Low Issue Date]) AS [MaxOfLow Issue Date], 
        qryPolyCalcParameters.[Interest Rate Code]
    FROM tblInsurance 
    INNER JOIN qryPolyLifeMasterPlans 
        ON tblInsurance.LM_PLAN_CODE = 
            qryPolyLifeMasterPlans.[LifeMaster Plan Code] 
    INNER JOIN qryPolyNonforfeitureValues 
        ON qryPolyLifeMasterPlans.[Nonforfeiture Value Code] = 
            qryPolyNonforfeitureValues.[Nonforfeiture Value Code] 
    INNER JOIN qryPolyCalcParameters 
        ON qryPolyNonforfeitureValues.[(Cash Value) Calc Parameters Code] = 
            qryPolyCalcParameters.[Calc Parameters Code]
    WHERE 
        qryPolyCalcParameters.[Low Issue Date]<[ISSUE_DATE] 
        AND tblInsurance.COMPANY_CODE='NL' 
        AND tblInsurance.LINE_OF_BUSINESS='IT' 
        AND tblInsurance.SchedNP='PAR'
        AND tblInsurance.TERM_REASON='A' 
        AND tblInsurance.ProdType='PERM' 
        AND tblInsurance.PHASE_CODE=0 
        AND tblInsurance.SUB_PHASE_CODE=1 
GROUP BY 
    tblInsurance.POLICY_NO, 
    tblInsurance.IssueYear, 
    tblInsurance.ISSUE_DATE, 
    tblInsurance.LM_PLAN_CODE, 
    tblInsurance.AMOUNT_INFORCE, 
    tblInsurance.StatReserve, 
    tblInsurance.StatReserveX, 
    tblInsurance.DefPremReserve, 
    tblInsurance.ExcessCashValue, 
    tblInsurance.ExcessCashValueX, 
    tblInsurance.STAT2_PUA_RES, 
    tblInsurance.STAT2_OYT_RES, 
    tblInsurance.StatOYTRes2X, 
    qryPolyCalcParameters.[Calc Parameters Code], 
    qryPolyCalcParameters.[Interest Rate Code]
```

That should help.  Then we can see about getting rid of the other nesting.  It's your subselects that a are killing your performance.

Comment: That chang turned it into a 2 second qry. Thank you so much. I'm going to do my best to apply this line of thought to many other qrys that take 5 minutes.

Comment: Glad it helped, but there is still some improvements possible.  I don't think you need any subselect.  Keep trying!  And please accept my answer.

Comment: Hold on I made a small mistake when i edited the qry. I accidentally deleted the top 2 selects. This is what I have now and now the qry won't function because the top 2 selects are in red. I think im probably just missing like a comma or ) somewhere but I can't find it

Comment: I can't post the new version of the qry here, if I edit the question and insert the new version will you help me find the problem?

Comment: @wagregg . . . Your point is well-taken.  However, the OP query is grouped by three columns and yours by many, many more.  I don't see how they are equivalent.

Comment: I wasn't trying to rewrite the entire query, just the most deeply nested subselect.  There was a pure select contained within a simple group by.  I was just trying to eliminate one subselect by stitching those 2 items together.  Sorry that wasn't more clear.

Comment: Well I can't get it to work within the entire qry, If you could show me how this would fit in to the whole that would be great

Comment: Could you post the scripts to create tblInsurance, qryPolyLifeMasterPlans, qryPolyNonforfeitureValues, and qryPolyCalcParameters?  Then I can make sure that it will work syntactically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole query simplified.

```
SELECT 
    qry_tempCashValue2.IssueYear, 
    qry_tempCashValue2.LM_PLAN_CODE, 
    Count(qry_tempCashValue2.POLICY_NO) AS CountOfPOLICY_NO, 
    qry_tempCashValue2.[Interest Rate Code]
FROM
(
    SELECT distinct
        tblInsurance.POLICY_NO, 
        tblInsurance.IssueYear, 
        tblInsurance.ISSUE_DATE, 
        tblInsurance.LM_PLAN_CODE, 
        tblInsurance.AMOUNT_INFORCE, 
        tblInsurance.StatReserve, 
        tblInsurance.StatReserveX, 
        tblInsurance.DefPremReserve, 
        tblInsurance.ExcessCashValue, 
        tblInsurance.ExcessCashValueX, 
        tblInsurance.STAT2_PUA_RES, 
        tblInsurance.STAT2_OYT_RES, 
        tblInsurance.StatOYTRes2X, 
        qryPolyCalcParameters.[Calc Parameters Code], 
        qryPolyCalcParameters.[Interest Rate Code]
        FROM tblInsurance 
        INNER JOIN qryPolyLifeMasterPlans 
            ON tblInsurance.LM_PLAN_CODE = 
                qryPolyLifeMasterPlans.[LifeMaster Plan Code] 
        INNER JOIN qryPolyNonforfeitureValues 
            ON qryPolyLifeMasterPlans.[Nonforfeiture Value Code] = 
                qryPolyNonforfeitureValues.[Nonforfeiture Value Code] 
        INNER JOIN qryPolyCalcParameters 
            ON qryPolyNonforfeitureValues.[(Cash Value) Calc Parameters Code] = 
                qryPolyCalcParameters.[Calc Parameters Code]
        WHERE 
            qryPolyCalcParameters.[Low Issue Date]<[ISSUE_DATE] 
            AND tblInsurance.COMPANY_CODE='NL' 
            AND tblInsurance.LINE_OF_BUSINESS='IT' 
            AND tblInsurance.SchedNP='PAR'
            AND tblInsurance.TERM_REASON='A' 
            AND tblInsurance.ProdType='PERM' 
            AND tblInsurance.PHASE_CODE=0 
            AND tblInsurance.SUB_PHASE_CODE=1 
    ) qry_tempCashValue2
GROUP BY 
    qry_tempCashValue2.IssueYear, 
    qry_tempCashValue2.LM_PLAN_CODE, 
    qry_tempCashValue2.[Interest Rate Code];

GO
```

Comment: It has just passed the 25 minute mark so its slower then the new version I have now based off of Gordans suggestion. Thank you for trying

Comment: Well that's disappointing.  Is there a lot of contention on those tables?  Would some NOLOCK hints help?

Comment: Only tbl insurance is a table the others are views. I think this must be why it takes so long. Sql has to run each of those qry's use din the joins which themselves contain tables and other qrys. Making this qry run faster is either impossible at this point or going to take a lot of effort.